# How to get the First Image from UICollectionViewCell and Save in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, uiimage, uicollectionview

I want to Save the First or the Last Image from the UICollectionView and Save it in the UITabelView Cell as UIImage.I try it with the first indexPath `if indexPath == 0` catch the UIImage and then save it in CoreData as NSData but it doest works. Have anyone an idea how can i make that or gives another way to Display the UIImage in the UITableViewCell? Thanks for Help.

Here was the code from the UICollectionViewCell:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BookPicCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookPicCell

    let cellcore = picture[indexPath.row]
    cell.BookImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: cellcore.foto!)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let firstpic = cell.BookImage.image
        let firstcell = UIImagePNGRepresentation(firstpic!)

        let firstimag = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! Book
        firstimag.firstimage = firstcell!
    }


    do {
        try self.mgdContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Here was the Code from the UITableViewCell:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let Cell = BookTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BookCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookCell

    let books = book[indexPath.row]
    Cell.BookTitle.text = books.title

    let picturecount = books.picture!.count
    Cell.BookImageCount.text = "\(picturecount) Picture"



    let firstpicture = books.firstimage!
    Cell.BookImage.image = UIImage(data: firstpicture)


    return Cell
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not describe the problem you're having. This page may help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to know that this code anyway worked with the `indexPath == 0` to catch to first Image of the Cell or to have anyone an idea how to get the first image from the cell.

Comment: Have you another idea what i can do there to get the image ?